# Use CMake's find_library to add an iOS Framework from a custom location

Tags: ios, cmake, frameworks

I'm trying to add an iOS framework called `WebPDecoder.framework` using CMake. I found that the right way to do this would be:

```
find_library(IOS_WEBP NAMES WebPDecoder PATHS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/ios" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

The framework folder is in the `lib/ios` folder, but CMake can't find it. Adding `--debug-find` I'm getting the following output:

```
  find_library called with the following settings:

    VAR: IOS_WEBP
    NAMES: "WebPDecoder"
    Documentation: Path to a library.
    Framework
      Only Search Frameworks: 0
      Search Frameworks Last: 0
      Search Frameworks First: 1
    AppBundle
      Only Search AppBundle: 0
      Search AppBundle Last: 0
      Search AppBundle First: 1
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH Enabled

  find_library considered the following locations:

  The item was not found.
```

Why is CMake ignoring my custom path?

Comment: It smells like the given output of `--debug-find` is NOT about the `find_library` call which you provide in the question post. E.g. the output tells about "NO_DEFAULT_PATH Enabled", but your `find_library` call has no NO_DEFAULT_PATH option.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ups, sorry. I've tried different things and accidentally copied the wrong line. I've fixed my question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It turned out that a copypasted CMake setup for iOS was setting `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY` to `ALWAYS`. To allow CMake to find the custom path under project source directory, the setting must be `BOTH` or `NEVER`.